# No module named twisted on Mac Mavericks

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to use scrapy, but it requires twisted.
I already tried many solutions suggested in other posts, but nothing worked. I have python 2.7 and gcc4.2.1 on a Mac Maverick.

```
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10:
> fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
> 
> #include <stdio.h>
> 
>          ^
> 
> 1 error generated.
> 
> error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

edited Oct, 25th, 2013 -----------------------------

Right, I installed the Mac Developer Tools, but now I get this message:

```
>     Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
> (from zope.interface>=3.6.0->twisted)
>     Installing collected packages: twisted, zope.interface
>       Running setup.py install for twisted
>         
>         /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3
> -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
```

What should I input now?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to install the Apple command line tools from the [Apple Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action), which will give you clang and other development headers needed for scrapy.

Comment: Right, I downloaded it, but I can't install it still

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano: Post the entire output of the command line, plus all of its output to a gist so we can see what you're doing!